# Where does a U-turning car get its energy from?

Tags: energy, momentum

When you're flying a spaceship (away from large bodies with gravity), and suddenly realize you've left the oven on and need to turn around, you need to burn $2E_k$ worth of fuel to do it (where $E_k$ is your kinetic energy): firstly to break to a stop, and secondly to accelerate in the opposite direction back to your previous speed.

However, when instead driving a car, you can just turn around (on a large enough radius so that you don't skid) when not in gear, without hitting the acceleration pedal at all (or even with your engine off). Sure, you'll lose some speed, but you can manage to somehow bypass this large energy requirement while changing your momentum to the entirely opposite direction.

Where does this extra energy come from when you turn a car around? What happens to your original energy? Mind you, it appears you only have $E_k = \frac{mv^2}{2}$ energy to begin with, but need **twice** that much to turn around in a vacuum.

I'm guessing tires and asphalt play a huge role here, but it seems quite counter-intuitive that they can somehow produce twice the energy you originally had. What provides that energy?

Comment: Students beginning their study of Physics sometimes find it hard to distinguish between the rôles of momentum and KE. This question nicely leads one to see that the same change in momentum can be associated with changes in KE or with no change at all in KE !

Answer (score 5):

You can turn your spaceship around without spending $2E_k$. Just go half-way round the Moon or some other planet. The point is that as long as the force changing your direction is always at  right-angles to your velocity vector, it does not  change your KE.  For  the cornering car, the static friction force on the tyres is at right angles to the car's velocity.

Comment: +1 good answer except that I think the static friction on the tires is NOT at right angles to the car's velocity.  Instead, the static friction force on the tire is at a right angle to the direction the TIRE is pointed.  Since the tires are not aligned with the car velocity vector, part of the static friction force is decelerating the car.  This is why the car slows down so much during the U-Turn.

Answer (score 2):

> When you're flying a spaceship (away from large bodies with gravity), and suddenly realize you've left the oven on and need to turn around, you need to burn 2Ek worth of fuel to do it (where Ek is your kinetic energy): firstly to break to a stop, and secondly to accelerate in the opposite direction back to your previous speed.

This is not true for several reasons.

First, rockets work by conservation of momentum between the rocket and the exhaust, so the energy that you must use if you are using your engines to execute this maneuver will also include all of the energy that you put into the rocket exhaust. If you track it carefully, you will find in fact that all of the KE goes into the exhaust and none into the rocket on average.

To put some specific math behind this statement suppose that the rocket works by firing one instantaneous burst of exhaust, all at the same velocity (it is possible to do a similar analysis using the rocket equation, but that adds some complexity that obscures the point). The rocket has mass $M$ and the exhaust has mass $m$ and leaves the rocket at a relative velocity of $v_e$. The initial KE of the rocket is $E_k=\frac{1}{2}M v^2$, and the energy from the fuel burned is $E_f$, so we can write conservation of energy and momentum as $$\frac{1}{2}M v^2 + \frac{1}{2}m v^2 + E_f = \frac{1}{2}M (-v)^2 + \frac{1}{2}m (v+v_e)^2$$$$M v + m v = M (-v) + m (v+v_e)$$ From this it is straightforward to show that $$E_f=\frac{1}{2}m (v+v_e)^2 - \frac{1}{2} m v^2$$ meaning that all of the energy from the fuel goes into increasing the KE of $m$ with none left for changing the KE of $M$. It is also straightforward to show that $$E_f=2 M v^2 + M v v_e = \left(4 + 2\frac{v_e}{v} \right) E_k \ne 2E_k$$ so, not only is the energy burned in the fuel never equal to $2E_k$, but also for large $v_e$ it can be arbitrarily large compared to $2E_k$

Second, you can do it for "free" if you happen to have a planet or star you can use. Although you excluded that in your question, the fact that it is possible shows that the energy "requirement" is not actually a physical requirement but is simply due to using an inefficient method.

> Where does this extra energy come from when you turn a car around?

There is no extra energy. You are just using a more efficient method. Similarly, if you hang a helicopter from a rope it hovers without expending any energy, but if you have it hover with its rotors it expends a lot of energy.

Comment: "you will find in fact that all of the KE goes into the fuel and none into the rocket on average."

– I don't understand what you mean. I thought you're using the chemical energy in the fuel to change the kinetic energy of the rocket..? What do you mean by "KE goes into the fuel", this sounds like fuel is actually gaining some of the ship's energy when burned..?

Also: 

"you can do it for "free" if you happen to have a planet or star you can use." – IIUC, that steals the energy from the planet or star, slowing it down a bit (albeit unnoticeably, due to the huge difference in mass).

Comment: @JayPulsar Sorry, I should have said "exhaust" not fuel there. I have edited. In the limit of a very large planet (compared to the rocket mass) no KE is removed from the planet. It really is "free", it is not just hidden. You should actually work out both of these computations

Comment: @JayPulsar, I'm not sure what Dale was saying there, but "energy" can be a tricky concept--especially if you try to compare energies in different frames of reference. In any frame that is rigidly attached to your ship, your ship _always_ has zero KE. It doesn't matter how fast you may be hurtling toward some distant planet. Your exhaust, on the other hand, which is flying away from you at ludicrous speed, has quite a lot of KE in that frame. But if your engine is firing, it's an _accelerated_ frame, and I'm not qualified to say anthing more specific about energy in accelerated frames.

Comment: Well, yeah, Tsiolkovski's rocket equation lowers the requirement a bit but that's just because it loses mass while ejecting fuel. I made a simplification in my argument to assume that the fuel doesn't weigh anything when in the tank. This doesn't change the fact that by comparison a car still needs way more than it has from its motion.

Indeed it's quite tricky.

Comment: @JayPulsar you are missing the point entirely. It isn't about the lost mass, it is about the energy from the fuel that goes into the exhaust. Since none of the energy goes into the rocket, it all goes into the exhaust. I have simplified it not using the rocket equation for clarity.

Comment: @Dale thanks for clarifications, I'm still not 100% sure what you mean by this, but this math you present definitely makes it clearer. My biggest problem with your answer, however, is that it doesn't explain what happens to the energy of the U-turning car, which was my main concern (I only tried to use the rocket to illustrate my point).

Comment: @JayPulsar said “it doesn't explain what happens to the energy of the U-turning car” That was the last paragraph. Nothing happens to the energy for a U turning car. There simply is no extra energy. There is nothing else to explain because the thing that you wanted explained simply doesn’t exist.